# How to use setSenderName and setSenderEmail from DocuSign\eSign\Model\FolderItemV2 on PHP API

Tags: php, docusignapi

I've got a docuSign dev sandbox. I m able to login correctly and send envelopes without any issues. But now, I am trying to use the methods setSenderName, setSenderEmail and setCompanyName from this class:

```
class FolderItemV2 implements ArrayAccess
{
     static $swaggerTypes = array(
    'owner_name' => 'string',
    'envelope_id' => 'string',
    'envelope_uri' => 'string',
    'status' => 'string',
    'last_modified_date_time' => 'string',
    'sender_user_id' => 'string',
    'sender_name' => 'string',
    'sender_email' => 'string',
    'sender_company' => 'string',
    'created_date_time' => 'string',
    'sent_date_time' => 'string',
    'completed_date_time' => 'string',
    'subject' => 'string',
    'expire_date_time' => 'string',
    'folder_id' => 'string',
    'folder_uri' => 'string',
    'recipients' => '\DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients',
    'recipients_uri' => 'string',
    'is21_cfr_part11' => 'string',
    'is_universal_signature_envelope' => 'string'
     );
```

Methods are already defined on FolderItemV2.php (https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-PHP-Client)

My code is pretty much like this:

```
$envelopeApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
$envelop_definition = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition();
$envelop_definition->setEmailSubject("[Test]");
$envelop_definition->setStatus("sent");
$envelop_definition->setRecipients($recipients);
$envelop_definition->setDocuments(array($document, $document2, $document3));
$envelop_definition->setEmailSettings($emailSettings);
```

Now, I tried this but I cannot figure out how to fit a folder into an envelope, anyway when I add these lines it does not send the envelope or show anything into $folder var:

```
$folder = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\FolderItemV2();
$folder->setFolderId('1');
$folder->setSenderName('NameABC');
$folder->setSenderEmail('acbc@abc.com');
$folder->setSenderCompany('ComapnayABC');
```

Debugmode is on and it shows the following message:

```
< *X-DocuSign-SDK: PHP Accept: application/json Content-Type: application/json 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
< Cache-Control: no-cache 
< Content-Length: 692 
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
< Date: Thu, 19 May 2016 04:29:33 GMT 
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains 
< * Connection #3 to host demo.docusign.net left intact*
```

I have read all documentation, if someone has already gone through this I'd really appreciate a tip. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Class`FolderItemV2` has nothing to do with EnvelopesApi::CreateEnvelope. It is a response item received from method `/v2/accounts/{accountId}/search_folders/{searchFolderId}`

If you want to set the Sender's name, then either:

1. Use Send On Behalf Of (SOBO) feature. This enables authorized "system" logins within your account to send on behalf of a user who is in the same account. [Docs](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#SOBO/Send%20On%20Behalf%20Of%20Functionality%20in%20the%20DocuSign%20REST%20API.htm).
2. Have each sender authorize your app by using SSO. Requires that the sender take the positive step to enter their SSO email/pw information and authorize your app. [Docs](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#DocuSignOAuth/docusign-oauth.htm%3FTocPath%3DDocuSign%2520OAuth%2520(Authorization%2520Code%2520Grant%2520or%2520Implicit%2520Grant)).
3. Have the sender authorize your app by supplying their email/pw to your app. [Not recommended]

The problem with option 2 is that you need to contact each of your internal users to go through the process of authorizing your app. That can be a lengthy process if you have many users.

If you're writing an app on behalf of the DocuSign account admin, then it often makes sense for the account admin to authorize your app to Send On Behalf Of the account's senders. Presumably your app won't abuse the privilege.